# Need help to fix a script with dynamic content

Tags: dynamic

I can't figure out why this is not working.  I'm trying to get different DIV tags to have different text content in a cycle loop.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> var text1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
> var i1 = 0,
> var text2 = ['hug', 'kiss001', 'bank22'];
> var i2 = 0,
> $(document).ready(function()
> {
>     setInterval(function (){
>             $("#DIV1").fadeOut(function ()
>         {
>             $("#DIV1").text(text[i1++ % text1.length]).fadeIn();
>         });
>     }, 1000);
>     setInterval(function (){
>         $("#DIV2").fadeOut(function ()
>         {
>             $("#DIV2").text(text[i2++ % text2.length]).fadeIn();
>         });
>     }, 1000);
> });
> </script>
> ```

```
<div id="DIV1"><div>  
<div id="DIV2"><div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bunch of syntax errors (`text` instead of `text1`/`text2`, no closing /div, etc. Works fine here: http://jsbin.com/obaqi4/3

Comment: Thank you...  here is the page:  http://www.myorphan.com/about.htm  how do eliminate the background from fading.  I only want he text to change.

Comment: Put the text you want to change inside a separate element. So for example, instead of `<div id="st1">...</div>`, use `<div id="st1"><div id="st1_inner">...</div></div>`, then target the javascript for #st1_inner, and apply all the styles to the outside div. This will ensure the external style sticks around while the text fades and changes.

Comment: BTW, the problem is that fade in/out fades the entire element by setting opacity. In order to just fade text (text by itself is not an element), you have to wrap it in an element that represents just the text.